# OpenCV-Python: What is correct shape of points for finding epipolar lines?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I'm having trouble using the computeCorrespondEpilines() function in OpenCV-Python. According to the documentation, the matrix of points is described as:

"Input points. N x 1 or 1 x N matrix of type CV_32FC2 or vector< Point2f >"

However, I'm not sure what this means in Python. I tried using a list of tuples but it was not a Numpy array, so I tried a Numpy array of tuples but it automatically converts to a Nx2 matrix. I also tried a Numpy structured array as a list of tuples, but the epilines function then says "points data type = 20 is not supported" which literally has 0 results in Google.

Does anyone know what is the correct shape/type of the matrix of points needed for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a catch. The type `CV_32FC2` is actually a type which contains two channels (values). The same goes with the vector.

So, actually it seems that the function is expecting 3D data with shape (N, 1, 2) or (1, N, 2). If you have a N x 2 matrix `M`, then you may use this:

```
MM = M.reshape((1,-1,2))
```

This should give a suitable array `MM` with shape (1, N, 2). If that does not work, then try:

```
MM = M.reshape((-1,1,2))
```

which gives a (N, 1, 2) array.

Also, `cv2` may be very picky about the data type, so you may try to cast your points into the correct type:

```
MM = M.reshape((-1,1,2)).astype('float32')
```

as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both ways but I still get a "format of point matrix is unsupported" error. But thank you for explaining the data type, I have a better understanding now!